# Move/copy range to start of current line

Tags: cut-copy-paste, range

I just learned about the shortcuts that allow you to manipulate ranges, e.g. `:+5,+10co.` to copy *after* the current line.

I wondered if there is a way to copy and move at the *start* of the current line?

Currently I have to move the cursor at the end of the preceding line in order to attain the desired result.

To illustrate, given the following file, with the cursor being at line 5:

```sh
  3 A
  4 B
→ 5
  6 C
  7 D
```

Applying a copy via `:+1,+2co.` results in the undesired empty line at line 5:

```sh
  3 A
  4 B
  5 
  6 C
→ 7 D 
  8 C
  9 D
```

Is there a way to copy at the start of the current line or is one limited to perform this command at the end of the preceding line?

Comment: `a way to copy and move at the start of the current line` That does not make sense for linewise (Ex) commands: "copy" can add _after_ or _before_ the current line. But it does not replace _existing_ lines (even empty ones). Either don't create unneeded empty lines, or delete them manually, or use "normal" commands.

Comment: That's unfortunate. The expectation I had of applying the copy command on the current line is that it would paste it _right after_ the cursor, without inserting a new line. It feels somewhat counter-intuitive to me, likely due to me being relatively new to vim. Is there a different or more idiomatic command you had in mind that would achieve the same?

Comment: The operation you describe is the equivalent of selecting _lines_ of text (i.e. including the line endings...CR or CRLF) in a gui/wysiwyg editor, hitting Ctrl-C (copy), placing the cursor on line 5, and hitting Ctrl-V (paste). Does that put the text on line 5 after the cursor? Nope. It puts it on the next line, leaving line 5 blank. As Matt indicates, you need characterwise operations and Normal (or Visual) mode is better suited for that then Command (line) mode.

Comment: An example of characterwise _but_ multiline operation (while in Normal mode): `g_` is a motion to the last non-blank character of the current line and [count-1] lines downward. So if we do `y2g_` we'll do a characterwise yank of two lines. Then we could do `5Gp` to move cursor to line 5 and paste yanked text after it. IOW, one might find it easier to remove line 5 first and use your original commands... ;)

Comment: You had one line then you've inserted two lines more. Now you have three lines in total. That's very intuitive, IMO. Just don't create that empty line and do `+1,+2co-1` or something like that.

Comment: That does make sense. Thanks for the motion @BLayer, I didn't know about that one! :-)

Comment: Cool. No problem. (I'm guessing a _lot_ of users are not familiar with that one. :)